# What is Linearly dependency

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have 3 vectors a, b and c.

And I know that a is NOT linear independent to either b or c, is there a chance that b and c are linear independent of each other?

Comment: I try to discourage people from talking about individual vectors as being linearly independent from other vectors.  It's more precise to talk about whether **sets of vectors** are linearly independent.  So you're saying that $\{a, b \}$ is linearly dependent and $\{a, c \}$ is linearly dependent, and asking whether $\{b, c \}$ can be linearly independent.  As the accepted answer demonstrates the answer is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  If $a=\alpha b$ and $a=\beta c$, then $c=\alpha/\beta b$.  So $b$ and $c$ are dependent.

So, it boils down to the fact that two vectors are linearly dependent if and only if they are multiples of each other.

Comment: Note that this depends on how we interpret the somewhat-ambiguous hypothesis "a is linear dependent of b and c." If it means "$a$ is linearly dependent on $b$ and $a$ is linearly dependent on $c$" then you're right; if it means "$a$ is linearly dependent on $\{b,c\}$" then the answer is the opposite.

Comment: @NoahSchweber  Right.  I got hung up on just that.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, I updated the question. Is it better now?

Comment: Yes.  That's better.

Comment: For your last answer, "Imagine a = (1,1) b = (1,0) and c = (0,1)", why it was wrong?

Comment: Because, now that you've adjusted it to be more clear, we wouldn't have $\{a,b\}$ and $\{a,c\}$ dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Linear independence is a property of a subset of a vector space.

Suppose $V$ is a vector space and $S$ a subset thereof. Then $S$ is a linearly independent set if the solution to the equation

$$\sum_{v_i \in S} c_i v_i = 0$$

requires all $c_i$ to be zero. We do not say that, for example, $x$ is linearly independent of $y$.

Intuitively, this means that all vectors point in all different directions. Check this for two vectors in the plane, and convince yourself that no collection of three vectors in two dimensional space can form a linearly independent set.

This concept generalizes to any vector space - not just those isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Function spaces have this notion too.

Another way to think of linear dependence is that one vector in the set can be expressed as a linear combination of the others. So, in your sense, if $a$ can be written as a linear combination of $b$ and $c$, then so can the other two.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because linear dependency means that $\vec{a}$ is a linear combination of $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$. (it can be expressed as let's say $3\vec{a} = 2\vec{b} + 7\vec{c}$)

For $\vec{b}$ to be linearly dependent on $\vec{c}$, it means $\vec{b}$ must equal to $k\vec{c}$, where k is some constant. (or $\vec{c} = k\vec{b}$, if you wish.)

However, just because $3\vec{a} = 2\vec{b} + 7\vec{c}$, does not mean that $\vec{b} = k\vec{c}$.
It means that $2\vec{b} = 3\vec{a} - 7\vec{c}$, which means $\vec{b}$ is linearly dependent on $\vec{a}$ AND $\vec{c}$ TOGETHER, but may not be linearly dependent on them alone. Of course it is possible it is linearly dependent of $\vec{b}$ alone (or $\vec{c}$ alone), when the constant in front of $\vec{c}$ is $0$.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, what I meant is  we wouldn't have {a,b} and {a,c} dependent